# How do you flag wording on the site as being incorrect?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags

How do you flag wording or grammar on the site as being incorrect if is part of the site and not a question/answer/comment?

When I go to down vote an answer I get the following text

> Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 125 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

I believe it should read

> Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 125 reputation are recorded but do not change the publicly displayed post score.

with out the comma after recorded and before but.

I know that you can have **, but** in a sentence but I do not believe it is correct in this instance.

Is there any way to flag this?

Comment: I'm not sure how the comma is bad. I find it easier to understand with the comma. Could you [edit] the question, to explain _why_ the comma makes it incorrect / harder to understand?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that it is wrong. I don't think it makes it easier to read with out the comma. I do believe it is grammatically incorrect, which is my point. Plus it was the first example I found.

Comment: You are technically correct here. When "but" is used as a coordinating conjunction, the comma is only proper if both clauses are independent (*i.e.*, could stand alone as separate sentences). The second clause here ("do not...") is a dependent clause because it does not have its own subject. However, even though improper, this usage is common because it makes the sentence easier to parse and understand, especially for non-native speakers.

Comment: I was just about to say *exactly* what @CodyGray said. Any rumours that I don't have the faintest idea about anything he's talking about here are completely false.

Comment: Any rumors that I have the faintest idea what I'm talking about are also false, @Pekka, so you're in good company.

Comment: Are the down votes because I have asked a bad question, because the correction I am suggesting is overly pedantic, because people think the comma should be there or something else I haven't thought of?
I would like to know for when I ask questions in the future.
Part of the reason for asking was just to highlight the grammar.

Comment: Here on Meta votes are also used to express disagreement. So it's possible that people downvoted because they want to keep the comma. Don't worry too much about it, unless many of your posts here get a negative score.

Comment: Not worried, more interested. I hope it is because people really care about punctuation. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't flag it. Flags are for things contributed by users, not for the automated texts in the system.

Instead, you can raise the issue on Meta, like you just did. You can tag it as "discussion" or as "feature-request". Personally I prefer the latter. You could also tag it as "bug", but grammatical issues in texts aren't really bugs IMO.

Comment: Thanks, I will amend the tag to include feature request.