# What constitutes a "petty edit?"

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Having just obtained 2000+ reputation I was going through questions flagged for edits. It seems that some of the question edits are very petty grammatical corrections. What would be the threshold for rejecting an edit based on such petty corrections as opposed to someone correcting serious errors?

I do realize it's a bit subjective, so I'm not looking for a bright line; I at least need to get in the gray area. Honestly, before seeing these edit requests, it never even occurred to me to edit people's questions for grammar, there are a lot people on here that have limited English and I just gloss over that.

Here's an example I have on my screen right now.
[image: Here's an example I have on my screen right now.]

I consider this a petty edit. Adding bold to a section and then putting in a missing semi-colon. I guess I can see where the semicolon would be helpful, but not adding bold formatting to someone's question. For this one, I removed the bold formatting and left the semi-colon insertion.

Here's an edit I am rejecting as being not at all helpful. Was it the right call?

[image: 2nd image.]

Comment: I'm on the fence about the latter edit. It is clearly well-intended and leaves the question in a better state — but it missed a few grammatical problems and didn't remove the salutation.

Comment: To me, unless the grammar is so bad the question cannot be understood, then go ahead and correct it. But correcting it when the meaning is clear seems petty. Also, when I'm asked to correct grammar, I'm brutal about it, but SO isn't English class, so it seems like an unneeded distraction.

Comment: One of the functions of SO/SE is to preserve questions and answers that may be useful reference to future visitors.  In that spirit, correcting objectively poor grammar improves the experience for readers.  Personally, I find the extra mental effort in parsing awkward phrasing an unwanted distraction, and I doubt I'm alone.  And, while this isn't English class, avid ESL learners welcome the help.

Comment: @Difster i disagree. The while users do use edits to gain rep, they can only gain a limited amount of rep via edits. So stop looking at edits as source of rep farming and add a means to name the past better (even if or its slightly better in some cases). Now it's you see the same user making numerous edits that are exactly the same minor issues, then f eel free to start rejecting and ma wife raise a mod flag

Comment: @psubsee2003 - I never framed this as reputation hunting. I didn't even bring it up.

Comment: Thanks for all the input everyone. I will be more judicious about rejecting edits from now on, now that I understand the extent of it.

Comment: @Difster I was mostly referring to the fact that your position (based on your comment) is it isn't necessary to edit understandable posts if there is still something wrong with regards to spelling or grammar.  The rep hunting statement was more related to the users editing and not your question.

Comment: Also, in the spirit of petty grammar edits, they should have added "that" not "which" - http://www.writersdigest.com/online-editor/which-vs-that.  My only problem with the second edit is that it wasn't thorough enough in grammatical corrections

Comment: I, personally, would have clicked "improve edit" for the second example, in order to remove the "Dears". The post was clearly grammatically incorrect and such mistakes just help perpetuate poor English, especially for non-native speakers. I look at edits being a sort of flag that have hopefully corrected most, if not all, of the errors in the post. If something was missed, then just improve the edit. If the suggested edit is rejected, then that post may disappear into the rest of the cloud of questions, and never have a chance at being corrected again.

Comment: I think it helps to correct the grammar in questions as otherwise people may mark down reasonable questions just because of the grammar. This is discussed in the following question. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253780/is-it-ok-to-downvote-questions-because-of-bad-grammar

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I might have rejected the first one as an attempt to reply. Where did that extra text come from? I also agree that randomly bolding text is not helpful (though for some reason it happens a lot).

But the second edit fixes objectively incorrect grammar. That's not petty, that's [what editors should be doing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing). An editor that fixes code indentation but leaves all the grammatical errors in the text is doing it wrong. The problem is that they left in all the noise. (There could be other issues but that's all that is visible.)

Note that the goal of Stack Overflow is to be *a library of detailed answers to every question about programming*. That means the content should be as clear and professional as possible.

> there are a lot people on here that have limited English

That's true but these edits aren't about picking at someone's English level. An edit that objectively fixes an error should not be taken personally. Also note that many users whose first language isn't English welcome these edits:

[Is it OK to flag own question/answer for English grammar moderation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352451/is-it-ok-to-flag-own-question-answer-for-english-grammar-moderation)

[Is it OK to ask for edits on my own posts to fix English?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353980/is-it-ok-to-ask-for-edits-on-my-own-posts-to-fix-english?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I would consider an edit that re-words text that is already clear and isn't wrong or changes the style of code that's already clear to be petty.

Since the goal of a suggested edit is to fix as much as possible, I generally:

- Approve edits that fix everything
- Improve edits that fix most things
- Reject or Reject & Edit that fix nothing or very little, or introduce new errors
- Reject edits cause harm
- Skip whenever I'm not sure

Comment: I find myself agreeing with an awful lot of your answers here lately. Would you perhaps be interested in taking over my role as opinionated loudmouth on Meta? :-)

Comment: You might want to explain **why** fixing grammar is an acceptable edit (i.e. professionalism and long-term value).

Comment: @CodyGray - I'm *very* flattered but unworthy.

Answer (score 21):

The second edit in your question that you rejected was mine.

I put in those changes to improve the question, I think if a question is poorly worded then people are less likely to answer and might think the person asking doesn't know as much as they can't phrase their questions properly. You don't always consider it could be a second language for them.

I think if you have just read a question and some of it is incorrect then surely the edits are to correct that.

I have only just started to contribute to this site after using it for a number of years without adding anything to it. I have contributed a few accepted answers to the site in the last couple of weeks as well as having made several edits to poorly worded/laid out questions.

I have also contributed to this meta site with answers and edits too which doesn't change your reputation.

If you don't accept the edits that actually improve question quality then you are leaving the site in a worse state. The example you gave of my edit is pedantic but it should be. If that edit had been rejected then there would have been a poorly worded question instead of a slightly better question.

For reference the other 2 reviewing the above edit approved them so it has been changed.

I should have removed where it said Dears as well but must have missed it.

Comment: And this is why I'm asking the question. If the standard is to alter grammar, and make those small changes, then so be it. Until seeing the edits other people were making I simply hadn't considered anything but the most egregious spelling and grammar errors to be of any real importance, especially considering (as I mentioned above) that so many people do not have English as their first language.

Comment: I know, I think there must be a cut off somewhere but to reject and edit which does correct issues in the question doesn't seem right. I get your point that until you started checking the edits what you did was correct spelling error and larger grammar issues but it does all help. I on the other hand am picky about grammar so thought everyone should be. Have a look at my meta question to see how pedantic I really can be. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354276/how-do-you-flag-wording-on-the-site-as-being-incorrect

Comment: Thanks for weighing in. I hope you didn't interpret this question as a personal attack, because it surely was not meant to be one. There has always been a lot of confusion surrounding whether or not to reject "trivial" edits, and therefore what exactly constitutes a "trivial" edit. For the record, I agree with you that fixing numerous spelling/grammar errors constitutes a useful and non-trivial edit, so please do continue suggesting these. If it's only a single misspelled word or a single missing comma, that's probably going to be trivial, so the rule of thumb is fix *everything* that's wrong.

Comment: I don't consider it that. I did have to answer as my edit was used. It is good to see that Difster is asking these questions soon after they began to approve and reject edits in an attempt to better the work that they are doing on the site.

Comment: @CodyGray - No, I didn't take it personally at all.

Comment: Hey Chris, keep it up, in my opinion these sorts of edits help out the site a lot (since answers are kind of the face of SO). Given the controversy around minor edits, if you are in doubt you may want to consider just leaving a comment under the post so that a higher rep user can fix it later if the answerer isn't really active anymore. It's not a perfect solution but [I have done this from time to time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18046247/using-html-instead-of-cshtml#comment75207081_18046247) as a workaround while SO figures out what really is too minor, I've had some success with it

Answer (score 19):

If the grammar in the text is improved then rejecting the edit is making the question poorer for anyone reading it later.

Comment: Quintessentially that.

Answer (score 10):

Adding the semicolon to the code was a big deal. In some cases, leaving things like that out could very well be the reason for the problem in the first place. Be very wary of code edits. In general, I do not modify code except:

- When I am adding in code the OP shared as a comment because they are new and don't know how to edit (in the edit summary, always explain that the code you're adding is from OP's comments!), or
- Fixing indentation and adding line breaks to make it readable without scrolling twenty feet with your mouse cursor. However, I only do those if:

  - I know for a fact that I can do so in that language with no consequence.
  - For splitting lines, that I can split it in a way that is not distracting.

As far as grammatical edits, try to hit all of them in one go. There are a lot of non-English as a first language speakers here, but the site does require English content. It is not that their questions are unwelcome, but that they need help asking in such a way that is not distracting from their real problem: their code. But those type of edits are not trivial.

Answer (score 5):

I am an expert on “petty edits” (been ‘spoken to’ by mods on various occasions for, shall we say, “excessive enthusiasm”). Here are some examples, in general and not in order:

1. Changing from US to UK spelling (or vice versa) – always, except for consistency within a post.
2. Swapping number and text formats (usually). For example `3` to `three`, though that is as recommended by experts for small integers in most circumstances (eg not age).
3. Line and paragraph breaks (unless they break up a wall of text or make a significant difference).
4. Number and currency formats (eg `10,000.00` and `10 000,00` / `€88` and `88 €`). An exception is that lakhs and crores should be reformatted.
5. Oxford commas and other pure style and word choices (eg `’` for
   `”`).
6. Italics and bold (where neither excessive nor confusing).
7. Capitalisation, eg where Upper is correct but Proper is in common
   use.
8. Relatively rare spelling that is used by a significant minority.
9. Correct name where alternative is well known (eg `M$` and `Microsoft Corporation`).
10. Expanding other standard abbreviations (eg `IMO`) used sparingly.
11. Changes to image descriptions.
12. Surplus blank spaces.

Specifically for code (to which the above do not apply):

13. Non-standard indentation, where non-standard is nevertheless in common use and reasonably clear (and works!).
14. Backticking parameters and constants that are not ambiguous (but may not apply for I to `I` for example).
15. Removal of line breaks (unless a block of them not required by the code).

The examples above are of changes that should not be edit suggestions *where the only ones required* by the post at the time. “Petty edits” may cease to be “petty” when part of more radical enhancements. Because of the review process for suggestions, the above does not apply to those with the edit privilege.

Comment: *Changes to image descriptions.* Interesting. Do you have an example of this that was considered petty? Because I find that the vast majority of alt text still says "enter image description here".

Comment: I've edited a couple of alt texts where someone put something but it wasn't useful. IIRC, in both instances it was a question that said something like, "I don't know how to describe this so here's an image" and the alt text was "screenshot of what I want" so the whole question went: "I don't know how to describe this so here's an image. screenshot of what I want. How do I do this?"

Comment: "the above does not apply to those with the edit privilege" - doesn't it though? Sure, it applies to a **greater** extent to those without edit privileges, but if you're editing an old question only to "fix" some arguably correct formatting, bringing the question back to the front page, that doesn't seem good.